# Covariance square error returned by GaussianProcessRegressor from scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

when I get Covariance from

```
 mu, cov = gpr.predict(test_X, return_cov=True)
```

Then take this step

```
uncertainty = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
```

Sometimes, it will report the following error

```
d:/WorkSpace/python/Reusecode/hyperOptimize/testPara.py:204: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
```

I'm not sure whether it's a common question in GaussianProcessRegressor, or I make something wrong

Comment: This `warning` is from [numpy.sqrt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html), when some of the value you have is negative , `An array of the same shape as x, containing the positive square-root of each element in x. If any element in x is complex, a complex array is returned (and the square-roots of negative reals are calculated). If all of the elements in x are real, so is y, with negative elements returning 'nan'.` Just try `np.sqrt(-1)`, you will get the same warning, and will return `nan`

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I guess that might be the case.But real question is why GaussianProcessRegressor prediction function return a negative matrix, in normal case, it should be positive for it follows  a Gaussian distribution with mean mu and variance cov.The above is my understanding of the Gaussian process. If there is something wrong, please correct me.

Comment: refer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182005/kernel-matrix-is-not-positive-definite)